# Is Google Cloud data region-local?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a hard requirement of having all the data to never leave the EU region.

Studying the [service terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms) from Google for Kubernetes, for example, reveals [this](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#6-google-kubernetes-engine-and-google-container-registry):

> 6.2 Transient Storage. Core Kubernetes Engine Customer Data may be stored transiently or cached in any country in which Google or its agents maintain facilities.

What would be a correct way to interpret this paragraph? Does that mean Google can still send the data overseas or elsewhere outside EU region?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of google cloud, it will depends on the type of service. Some managed service will have some transient datas like Kubernetes core in your case, but it should not contains your customers datas, only datas specifics to your kubernetes configuration as the name implies.

Comment: Would you point me to the relevant discussions, where it was discussed, please? I'd like to learn more on the topic.